# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined in Angular template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

This is my service

```
getCADataService() : Observable<Currentaffairs[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Currentaffairs[]>(`${this.url}/sports`);
   }
```

This is my component:

```
getCAdata() {
        this.dataservice.getCADataService()
          .subscribe(currentAffairs =>
          this.currentAffairs = currentAffairs
        )
```

This is my Template:

```
  <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let ca of currentAffairs | keyvalue">
              <md-card class="example-card">
                <md-card-header>
                    {{ca.articles.description}}
                </md-card-header>
                <img md-card-image src="">
                <md-card-content>
                  <p>
                      
                  </p>
                </md-card-content>
                <md-card-actions>
                  <button md-button>Approve</button>
                  <button md-button>Reject</button>
                </md-card-actions>
              </md-card>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

While displaying data in UI i am getting below error:

Comment: response in postman                                                                                                                    {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 67,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "espn-cric-info",
                "name": "ESPN Cric Info"
            },
            "author": "Umar",
            "title": "PCB chairman Ehsan ",
            "description": "\"Legally and constitutionally it's our right to participate in the tournament and nobody can remove us from it\""
 },

Comment: What is `currentAffairs` set to before `getCAdata` is called? My guess is the template is trying to render before the subscription finishes. You can either add an *ngIf to not display this list until the thing has data, or try setting it to an empty array (though I think you'll get a different error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use `?` value in the `html` template to define it as a safe navigation operator as when the component loaded the observable is still ongoing hence it returns as `undefined`

```html
<ul>
            <li *ngFor="let ca of currentAffairs | keyvalue">
              <md-card class="example-card">
                <md-card-header>
                    {{ca.articles?.description}}
                </md-card-header>
                <img md-card-image src="">
                <md-card-content>
                  <p>
                      
                  </p>
                </md-card-content>
                <md-card-actions>
                  <button md-button>Approve</button>
                  <button md-button>Reject</button>
                </md-card-actions>
              </md-card>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the http response you provided it seems that you should iterate over the `articles` array or map your GET response to articles at first.

Right now you are trying to access here `{{ca.articles.description}}` a property `description` of an Array which doesn't make much sense.

One viable approach would be to adjust this method

```
getCAdata() {
    this.dataservice.getCADataService()
      .pipe(map((response) => response.articles));
      .subscribe(currentAffairs =>
      this.currentAffairs = currentAffairs
    )
}
```

so that `this.currentAffairs` is an array `aricles` itself and then you would remove `keyvalue` pipe and change the template in this way

```
<md-card-header>
  {{ca.description}}
</md-card-header>
```